# setAutoresizingMask does not work when child view is rotaed through some angle

Tags: ios

```
[ myChildeView setAutoresizingMask:( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight )];
```

This does not work if I rotate myChildeView through some angle. Can anybody help me out. Thanks